# Export attribute on nullable property causes crash

Tags: mono, monomac

Using mono 2.10.9 and monomac, I have written a c# class inheriting NSObject used for Cocoa-binding from Xcode. If my class includes a property using a nullable value like this:

```
[Export]
public bool? IsRegistered  { get; set; }
```

my application crashes the ugly way during startup (see crash report below). The main window hasn't even been displayed yet. As soon as I change the bool? to bool, everything works fine, but I actually would like to use bool?. Any suggestions?

Crash report:

```
Process:         SQAT [44677]
Path:            /Users/USER/*/SQAT.app/Contents/MacOS/SQAT
Identifier:      SQAT
Version:         4 (1)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [136]

Date/Time:       2013-01-23 15:31:51.540 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
objc[44677]: garbage collection is OFF
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95da69c6 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x90dc0f78 pthread_kill + 106
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x90db1bdd abort + 167
3   libmono-2.0.dylib               0x0029eefd mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 685
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x90e1659b _sigtramp + 43
5   ???                             0xffffffff 0 + 4294967295
6   libmono-2.0.dylib               0x002ed970 mono_runtime_posix_install_handlers + 288
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x90db1bdd abort + 167
8   libmono-2.0.dylib               0x003ff47f monoeg_g_logv + 159
9   libmono-2.0.dylib               0x003ff4ab monoeg_assertion_message + 43
10  libmono-2.0.dylib               0x0035a4ee mono_marshal_emit_managed_wrapper + 782
11  libmono-2.0.dylib               0x0035ae50 mono_marshal_get_managed_wrapper + 752
12  libmono-2.0.dylib               0x0035b2a2 mono_delegate_to_ftnptr + 146
13  ???                             0x011bf4be 0 + 18609342
14  ???                             0x011bf45c 0 + 18609244
15  ???                             0x01203350 0 + 18887504
16  ???                             0x01203148 0 + 18886984
17  ???                             0x013340fc 0 + 20136188
18  ???                             0x011c10a8 0 + 18616488
19  ???                             0x011c090c 0 + 18614540
20  ???                             0x01205cd8 0 + 18898136
21  ???                             0x0092bfe0 0 + 9617376
22  ???                             0x0092b6dc 0 + 9615068
23  ???                             0x0092bdde 0 + 9616862
24  libmono-2.0.dylib               0x0020dca4 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 164
25  libmono-2.0.dylib               0x003832e4 mono_runtime_invoke + 68
26  libmono-2.0.dylib               0x003893ae mono_runtime_exec_main + 238
27  libmono-2.0.dylib               0x002735fd mono_main + 6797
28  SQAT                            0x000394bf main + 3135
29  SQAT                            0x00038875 start + 53
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to bool? in ObjectiveC, so currently it is not possible to export such a property.

Exactly how are you trying to use this property from ObjectiveC?

Comment: Ok, that explains a lot. I was trying to bind some properties of an object to a NSObjectController, but that was obviously a wrong approach. Thanks.